# Is there any "app protocol" that is the letter G?

Tags: protocols

I want to know if there is any URL app launcher or something like that (I don't know what it is) that uses this (there can be missing letters before the G if so) * G://online-not-pc.example.link 
What does the G stand for or used? iPhone's Safari doesn't regonize it obviously.
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you wondering? What it the actual problem you want to solve?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no definite answer to this. Such a scheme *may* be implemented somewhere somehow, and even if it isn't today, it may be tomorrow…

Comment: I got a link that has this format, and I don't know what could it be. I know there is http, ftp, https, etc., but what about G://? There can be letters in front of it, like ag://, og, hppg://, no idea. Thank you.

Comment: And where did you get this "link" from? Are you sure it's a "link" that you put in the web-browser and not a link to a (Windows) file on the `G` drive? Was it really two leading slashes? Forward or backward slashes?

Comment: "G://www.smarturl.it/*"

Comment: Well, anyone can write anything anywhere. In what context did you encounter this and why do you think it's "a thing"?

Comment: https://twitter.com/gsmarturl/status/852015227625287680

Comment: Inside joke…? This is too obscure to waste any brain cycles on.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. There is no protocol for g:\\

Here is a [full list](https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml) of the URI scheme as approved by IANA.org.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: Citation added.

Comment: So there's no *officially IANA approved URI scheme g://*. That's a bit different from "doesn't exist".

Comment: Sure, if you want to be pedantic about. I took the question as meaning, existing on the publicly available internet. It's entirely possible someone is using their own internal version somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be checking URI scheme lists online to see if I find anything XXg:// because there's a gg:// on there and it could be anything